# Invoke function after response

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I am trying to separate one large function into multiple smaller ones. Using the following:

```
getSites() {
  this.http.get(`https://example.com/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Master')/items?$select=*,Hub/Title&$expand=Hub&$filter=Hub/Title eq 'Project Hub' and Active eq 'Yes'`).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(`project sites`, data['value'])
    this.sites = data['value']
    this.getLists() //Wait for this.sites to populate, then fire
  })
}

getLists() {
  this.sites.forEach(site => {

    this.http.get(`${site['Site']}/_api/web/lists/?$select=*&$filter=BaseTemplate eq 171`).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Site's lists", data['value'])
      this.getTasks(data['value'], site)
    })

  })
}
```

However, `getLists()` is firing before `this.sites` can fully populate from the first request. How can I solve this?

Comment: What you are saying can't be. You are calling `getLists` after you assign the value to `sites`. So, what actually is your problem?

Comment: getList is called after the sites request is completed so it's very unlikely that you are running into this problem. Are you sure `getList` is not called elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe you could pass the value from your 1st HTTP request into your `getLists` method?

Comment: you could try callback

Comment: You can turn getSites into a promise by doing this.http.get('blah').toPromise().then((sites)=> this.getLists(sites)).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subscribing in both function you could use a concatMap pipe (which will wait until getSites completes)

```
getSites():Observable<any>{
    this.http(...).pipe(map(() => ....)
}
getList(): Observable<any>{
    // do some stuff
}

// and use it like this 
getSites().pipe(contactMap((getSiteResult) => getList(getSiteResult)).subscribe()
```

hope it helps